# Rendering a date via lightning:formattedDateTime

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, date

When using date.today() for a community page it shows as yesterdays date in the community. If you look up the record in the system it shows properly as today. I've seen the post about the users timezone setting but even after switching it to CST (my actual timezone) its still showing as yesterday in the community. Has anyone else experienced this and if so, is there a work around?

Currently I am using `Date.Today().addDays(1);` so that todays date is displayed in the community but that makes it so in the system the date is showing the next day.

Code:

Front end:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(eBenchmark.Last_Modified_Date__c))}">
   <span><lightning:formattedDateTime timeZoneName="short" value="{!eBenchmark.Last_Modified_Date__c}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"/></span>
<aura:set attribute="else">
   <span>-</span>
</aura:set>                                                    
</aura:if>

<div id="{!eBenchmark.Id}" class="asmt-button" onclick="{!c.setSStatus}" >Undo</div>
```

Controller (I've tried these variations, all showing as yesterday in the community):

```
bMark.Last_Modified_Date__c = dateTime.now().date();
bMark.Last_Modified_Date__c = date.Today();
bMark.Last_Modified_Date__c = dateTime.now().addHours(3).date();
```

Full Controller class:

```java
    @auraenabled
    public static Assessment_Benchmark__c setSubStatus (Id benchmarkId){

       Assessment_Benchmark__c bMark = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Submission_Status__c, Last_Modified_Date__c FROM Assessment_Benchmark__c WHERE id = :benchmarkId];

        if(bMark.Submission_Status__c == 'Postponing'){
            bMark.Submission_Status__c = 'Not Submitted';
            bMark.Last_Modified_Date__c = dateTime.now().date();
        }
        else {
        bMark.Submission_Status__c = 'Postponing';
        bMark.Last_Modified_Date__c = dateTime.now().date();
        }
        update bmark;
        return bmark; 
    }
```

The javascript just calls the apex class and then refreshes the page so the new field values are displayed

Comment: How are you rendering the date in the community page/UI

Comment: `<span><lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.accInfo.Partner_Info_Modified_Date__c}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"/></span>
`

Comment: Add `timeZoneName` to `lightning:formattedDateTime` and update your post with more details on how you're setting the `Partner_Info_Modified_Date__c` field (controller, trigger, etc). Showing the code is encouraged.

Comment: Your post says you are using `date.today()` but your comment says you are using `Partner_Info_Modified_Date__c`.  Please edit your post to clarify this and include your code.

Comment: Code added, I am setting various fields such as Partner_Info_Modified_Date__c, Last_Modified_Date__c and others using date.Today(); in my apex controller. I didnt add code initially because there are several different fields being set at different places in my code. The key part is that I am setting all these fields using Date.Today() (or one of the other variations above) which is displaying correctly in the system but not in the community.

Comment: Update: if I remove `year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"` it shows the correct day but just not the format I want